# DOM Elements disappear on refresh angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, dom

I've simple page that was developed using angularjs. I'm seeing very weird issue with a table that i'm displaying on my page. When the page initially loads the table shows up properly with all the intended columns and its corresponding data, but upon refresh two of the columns go missing and upon refreshing again a couple of times the data columns and data comes back.

I've set a break point on the scope variable that I'm binding with those fields that looks good meaning there is always data in those variables. I'm really clue less to understand what is going on with this. I'm particularly curious to know why the two column headers are also being removed (if there is not data associated it should just show the blank fields) because  tag doesn't have any code to hide it based on the field's data and unfortunately this is happening only in prod and not in my lower environment. If anyone ever faced this situation and found a fix, please let me know. I'm using chrome browser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I know this comes on my way, but as I explained in my question I'm not able to replicate it in my lower environment, hence not able to replicate. Even if I share some code that would be working code only, which may not be much helpful.

Comment: The thing is, that, without any code, we can't really help you...we need a way to reproduce the issue, without that, you can check the Network tab and see if the data comes correct every time that you refresh, with that in place then the code should have some bugs...so first, check the data is right on every call, then check the code that renders the table.

Comment: I've tried all those trouble shooting steps, that is how I got to know that the data is coming back from server on every call and the scope variable is being assigned with correct data. However, I agree with you that that without the code that recreates the issue, can't do much.

Comment: The issue finally turned out to be a deployment issue, there are two bundles of template files existed on the server IE smart in picking up the latest bundle and unfortunately chrome is not it is randomly picking the bundle.